# Flash CS3 Compoenent "import" method and stucture?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, flash-cs3

hi I had seen one code of the yahoo map component for the **flash cs3**

like

```
import com.yahoo.maps.api.YahooMap;

var map:YahooMap = new YahooMap(); 

// include app-id, width and height
map.init("YD-vbXGXH4_JXs3ihv485hjXA--", 550, 400);  

addChild(map);
```

What i want is to make the import structure is like above "com.yahoo.maps.api.YahooMap;"

i created a small component and imported to flash lib all are working fine. But one problem is there it contains 3 functionality. ie  in my component i need to call there sub components from inside my orgianl component.

so i just need to

```
import mycomponent;
var myC = new mycomponent();
addChild(myC);
```

But i would like to call with my componentname like

```
 import com.MYComponen.subcomponent1;
 import com.MYComponen.subcomponent2;
var myC = new subcomponent1();
addChild(myC);
```

for this how i need to put my class and how can i make this path.
Hope you understood. sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your classes in a directory like :

```
/your root of source files/com/MyComponen/subcomponent1.as
```

and

```
/your root of source files/com/MyComponen/subcomponent2.as
```

And into you both `classes` declare the `package` where they belongs:

**for subcomponent1 for example**

```
package com.MyComponen {
 public class subcomponent1 {
  //...
 }
}
```

*As a naming convention*:
`Packages` names begin with a lower case and `Classes` with an upper case:

so your example become:
`package com.myComponen {...}` and `public class SubComponent1 {...}`